# Is it ok to ask for examples of UX for certain type of website if we ask for the features that make it a good design?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is it ok to ask for examples of good ux sites that have a certain purpose if you're asking for why are they outstanding?

Such as "What are good examples of search engines and what features make their UX distinctly better?" or "Which features are most important in portfolio websites and what are good examples of sites that use those features?"

Answer (score 1):

There is no correct answer to a question of "show me some examples of...". Each answer is just as relevant as the other. Plus new ones would come along and make any 'accepted' answers less relevant.

Really they're no more than polls. People post an example and voters vote for their favourite.

[Here's a Stack Exchange blog post about such poll questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) that explains why they're not really suitable.

So no, Stack Exchange isn't really set up site such questions.

To be honest it's a bit like going to a library and looking for a telephone directory for nearby book shops. You're *in the place where you can actually get the direct answers to whatever problem you have*. So instead of saying "can you UX experts show me where I can go to get some ideas". Just explain the problem you have and we'll give you that actual answer here. :)